# How to change color to only one bar on plotly bar plot?

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart

I have this plot:

```
Especie <- c("Perros","Gatos","Pájaros","Total")
Cantidad <- c(3,2,4,9)

df <- data.frame(Especie,Cantidad)

grafico <- plot_ly(df,
        x = ~Especie,
        y = ~Cantidad,
        type = "bar")
```

Is it possible to conditionally get the "Total" bar to be painted a different color, based on that particular value on the 'Especie' column?
Alternatively, is it posible to get the bar with the highest value on 'Cantidad' to be painted a different color?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option using an conditional statement `ifelse` to your `marker` of colors like this:

```
library(plotly)
grafico <- plot_ly(df,
                   x = ~Especie,
                   y = ~Cantidad,
                   type = "bar",
                   marker = list(color = ifelse(df$Especie == 'Total', "red", "blue")))
grafico
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to map a condition on the color attribute:

```r
library(plotly)

plot_ly(df,
  x = ~Especie,
  y = ~Cantidad,
  color = ~Especie == "Total",
  type = "bar",
  showlegend = FALSE
)els
```

[image]